# How do you set PanelHeight in TDBCtrlGrid?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use `TDBCtrlGrid`, which looks like a very useful and user friendly control.
I want to have just a single `TJvDBDateTimePicker` on it, so that the user can edit dates in a straightforward way.
It basically works, but I can't get the panel to take the height I want.
It seems that `PanelHeight`, a published property does nothing.
It's RowCount that controls the height, but that is no good.

Comment: Please provide a little more info. What version of delphi are you using? I seem to be unable to reproduce your problem, PanelHeight property works fine for me, it internally increases each panel height, increasing the total height of the TDBCtrlGrid

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2009. The problem may be what Francois said: that unlike a DBGrid, you have to maintain the scroll box etc. I think I'll give up on DbCtrlGrid.

Comment: What I meant to say was, the number of rows is determined by the RowCount property and it tries to show all rows on itself, unlike a DBGrid.

Comment: @Mark - The control only displays 'RowCount' number of rows, if there are more records of the bound dataset then they will be scrolled. IOW, the RowCount property is exactly like the protected 'RowCount' property of a DBGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its Align or Constraints properties are not messing up with its Height.

When using the defaults (align None and constraints 0), then Height, PanelHeight and RowCount are linked and calculated like:
**Height** = PanelHeight x RowCount if you change **PanelHeight or RowCount**
or
**PanelHeight** = **Height** / RowCount if you change **Height**

Answer (score 0):

Google gave me this link, I had the same problem. A DBCtrlGrid with top and bottom anchors in a PageControl on a form that could be resized.

Hopefully this may help someone who comes later. Skip to last line to solution if one isn't interested in the fails :)

I was hoping that PanelHeight could be static and RowCount would increase/decrease as Form height increases/decreases.

I had a few dead ends - one was on the tabsheet resize event to do a
if CadetTOR2.PanelHeight>pnlMax then CadetTOR2.RowCount:= CadetTOR2.RowCount+1;
but this was an endless loop as PanelHeight was not being updated quick enough

So a one off calculation is probably the most appropriate

I had a DBCtrlGrid, 26 in PanelHeight , 23 RowCount, that is 598 in total height - I wish the total height and RowCount to be variable, but PanelHeight to be roughly static.

I tried to anchor the grid top and bottom and set grid.RowCount=grid.height div 26 .. this didn't work, the grid collapsed into itself as it shrunk

this did work, DBCtrlGrid1 anchored top and left

```
procedure TfrmMain.TabSheet7Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DBCtrlGrid1.RowCount:= (TabSheet7.height-112) div 26;
end;
```